# Can someone give zakat to his unmarried (and young) brother?

Tags: zakat

السلام عليکم،

I know that one can give zakat to his brother if he is poor, but someone confused me saying:

You cannot give zakat to your brother if he is not married (and young) and have father as supporter.

Please help.